# inserting a document where the value of one key is an array variable

Tags: mongodb, insert

I am try to insert a document using the insert(). The document has a key field called ancestors with value as an array of ids. This codes is as follows;

```
var ids = [];
var fid = db.facultis.find({fname: "Sciences"})._id;
ids.push (fid);
var did = db.departs.find({dname: "Chemistry"})._id;
ids.push (did);
db.programs.insert({ prgname: "B.Sc. Pure Chemistry", ancestors:ids})
```

When run the code on MONGO shell and `find()` method it displays the following document.

```
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("570b8380d63a4e26124c8c36"),
       "prgname" : "B.Sc. Pure Chemistry",
       "ancestors" : [
            null,
            null
       ],
      "duration" : 4,
    )"
```

Why are the values of the "ancestors" field all null?

Answer (score 0):

The elements of that field are null because you are using the wrong method to get the `_id` values; you are using **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)** which returns a cursor to the selected documents in the collection, not the actual document hence when you 
try to access the `_id` property of a cursor object, it returns null.

You most probably want to use the **[`findOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#db.collection.findOne)** method which returns a single document that satisfies the specified query criteria, thus you can get the `_id` field:

```
var ids = [];
var fid = db.facultis.findOne({fname: "Sciences"})._id;
ids.push (fid);
var did = db.departs.findOne({dname: "Chemistry"})._id;
ids.push (did);
db.programs.insert({ prgname: "B.Sc. Pure Chemistry", ancestors: ids})
```